# When I am trying to bind the EIP to an Alibaba Cloud ECS Instance it doesn`t work

Tags: ip, alibaba-cloud, eip, alibaba-cloud-ecs

When I am trying to bind the EIP to an Alibaba Cloud ECS Instance it doesn`t work.

```
https://vpc.aliyuncs.com/?Action=AssociateEipAddress
&AllocationId=eip-25877c70x
&InstanceId=i-25skktcp4
&CommonParameters
```

I can`t even ping the IP address, Am I need to convert the public IP to EIP instead of binding new EIP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ECS instance has already public IP you can't attach EIP to that public interface.

[image: Unable to bind EIP because all ECS have public IP address]

You can assign EIP to a running ECS instance without a public IP address.

[image: Able to bind EIP to ECS without public IP address]

If you want to bind EIP to a running ECS instance with public IP address first you must stop the instance and attach EIP.

[image: ECS with public IP address]

[image: Able to add EIP to ECS in stopped state]